# What is the shape of the set of integer sided acute triangles with largest side n?

Tags: computational-geometry

I played around with Gauss circle problem and found that if you take a certain sum in reverse and "in forward" and subtract the resulting sequences you get the OEIS sequence:

https://oeis.org/A247588

starting:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 11, 13, 15, 17, 21, 25, 27, 31, 34, 39, 43, 48, ...
```

My question is: What is the shape of the lattice point set that is counted by this sequence?

Introduction:
Consider the number triangle defined by the Mathematica program:

```
nn = 12;
(*Mathematica program 1 start*)(*The number triangle above*)TableForm[
 Table[Sum[
   Table[If[
     And[If[n^2 + k^2 <= r^2, If[n >= k, 1, 0], 0] == 1, 
      If[(n + 1)^2 + (k + 1)^2 <= r^2, If[n >= k, 1, 0], 0] == 0], 1, 
     0], {k, 0, r}], {n, 0, r}], {r, 0, nn}]]
(*Mathematica program 1 end*)
```

This an infinite lower triangular matrix starting:

$$\begin{array}{lllllllllllll}
 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 2 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 2 & 1 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}$$

It might be of importance that the row sums are equal to the natural numbers.

Then take the total of the partial sums "in forward".

```
(*Mathematica program 2 start*)
(*How the number triangle above relates to one eight of a circle*)
a2 = Table[
  Total[Accumulate[
    Reverse[Sum[
      Table[If[
        And[If[n^2 + k^2 <= r^2, If[n >= k, 1, 0], 0] == 1, 
         If[(n + 1)^2 + (k + 1)^2 <= r^2, If[n >= k, 1, 0], 0] == 0], 
        1, 0], {k, 0, r}], {n, 0, r}]]]], {r, 0, nn}]
(*Mathematica program 2 end*)
```

The output from the program is the sequence:

```
1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 15, 20, 25, 32, 40, 49, 57, 66,...
```

which is the same as the number of lattice points within one eight of Gauss circle problem.

Comparison:

```
(*Mathematica program 3 start*)
(*One eight of a circle the usual way for comparison*)
Table[Sum[
  Sum[If[n^2 + k^2 <= r^2, If[n >= k, 1, 0], 0], {k, 0, r}], {n, 0, 
   r}], {r, 0, nn}]
(*Mathematica program 3 end*)
```

Output:
    1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 15, 20, 25, 32, 40, 49, 57, 66,...

Then take the total of the partial row sums in reverse of the lower triangular number triangle at the beginning of the question.

```
(*Mathematica program 4 start*)
(*How the number triangle above relates to the number of integer \
sided triangles*)
a4 = Table[
  Total[Accumulate[
    Sum[Table[
      If[And[If[n^2 + k^2 <= r^2, If[n >= k, 1, 0], 0] == 1, 
        If[(n + 1)^2 + (k + 1)^2 <= r^2, If[n >= k, 1, 0], 0] == 0], 
       1, 0], {k, 0, r}], {n, 0, r}]]], {r, 0, nn}]
(*Mathematica program 4 end*)
```

Output:
    1, 4, 8, 13, 20, 27, 36, 47, 58, 70, 83, 99, 116,...

Then take the difference of the a2 and a4 and divide it by 2:

In other words, this sequence:
    1, 4, 8, 13, 20, 27, 36, 47, 58, 70, 83, 99, 116,...
minus this sequence:
    1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 15, 20, 25, 32, 40, 49, 57, 66,...
divided by 2, which is:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 11, 13, 15, 17, 21, 25, 27, 31, 34, 39, 43, 48, ...
```

---

```
What is then the geometric, figurative number, meaning of this sequence
as it relates to Gauss circle problem?
```

I know from the OEIS that it counts integer sided acute triangles, but it should also count some lattice point set within a circle.

Comment: Sounds more like a question for math.SE. Otherwise, please explain what your Mathematica angle is.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But when posting programs to Mathematics stackexchange I have the feeling that nobody reads my programs.

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/acute-triangle.html

Comment: can you make this a complete question? You haven't stated anything about what the problem is.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have now rewritten the question.