# What is the geometric 2-dimensional shape of the following sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices

What is the geometric 2-dimensional shape of the following sequence:

{1, 4, 8, 13, 20, 27, 36, 47, 58, 70, 83, 99, 116, 132, 151, 170, 
192, 214, 238, 262, 287, 316, 343, 373, 405, 435, 468, 502, 539, 576, 
613, 654, 693,...}

It is generated by this program:

```
(*Mathematica program start*)
nn = 32;
a4 = Table[
  Total[Accumulate[
    Sum[Table[
      If[And[If[n^2 + k^2 <= r^2, If[n >= k, 1, 0], 0] == 1, 
        If[(n + 1)^2 + (k + 1)^2 <= r^2, If[n >= k, 1, 0], 0] == 0], 
       1, 0], {k, 0, r}], {n, 0, r}]]], {r, 0, 
   nn}]
(*Mathematica program end*)
```

This question is the first step that needs to be solved in order to answer this other question:

[What is the shape of the set of integer sided acute triangles with largest side n?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209266/what-is-the-shape-of-the-set-of-integer-sided-acute-triangles-with-largest-side#comment2470902_1209266)

I have tried programming this in a spreadsheet but I am not getting anywhere.

Trying to break down the question further: This arrayplot is closely related to the 14-th term of the sequence above:

```
r = 14;
ArrayPlot[
 Table[Table[
   If[And[If[n^2 + k^2 <= r^2, If[n >= k, 1, 0], 0] == 1, 
     If[(n + 1)^2 + (k + 1)^2 <= r^2, If[n >= k, 1, 0], 0] == 0], 1, 
    0], {k, 0, r}], {n, 0, r}]]
```

[image: 14-th term]

Comment: Did you try [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i={1%2C+4%2C+8%2C+13%2C+20%2C+27%2C+36%2C+47%2C+58%2C+70%2C+83%2C+99%2C+116%2C+132%2C+151%2C+170%2C+192%2C+214%2C+238%2C+262%2C+287%2C+316%2C+343%2C+373%2C+405%2C+435%2C+468%2C+502%2C+539%2C+576%2C+613%2C+654%2C+693%2C...})? It sounds like an answer would roughly be a copy-paste job from this page. What is your actual question?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Thanks for the comment. But I am not looking for the graph of the sequence. I want to know which geometric area in a point lattice that the shape encloses. Analogous to the way a circle encloses points in Gauss Circle Problem: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html.